# Правильная выборка из MYSQL

Tags: mysql

есть 2 таблицы в Mysql 
1. Таблицы inbox [image: Таблица inbox]

2. Таблица outbox [image: Таблица outbox]

Как вы уже поняли то в Inboxe хранится операции прихода а в outboxe операции расхода денег, В таблице inbox поле inbox_date отвечает за дату прихода а inbox_sum за сумму поступления. Так же в таблице outbox в поле outbox_date хранится дата расхода и в поле outbox_sum хранится сумма расхода. (Остальные поля не имеют никакого значения к этому вопросу)Внимание вопрос : Какой запрос следует сделать чтоб вывести данные в HTML таблице вот в таком виде : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите хотя бы в какую сторону копать и какую команду использовать. в MYSQL я новичок. 
PS насчет построения HTML таблицы не надо отвечать просто нужен правильный запрос из БД

Comment: Таблицу прихода группируете по дате (group by), оборачиваете в внешний запрос и подклеиваете (join) расход по дате. получаете на выходе выборку в каждой строке которой есть общая сумма прихода на дату и конкретного одного расхода. А дальше уже дело за оформлением

Comment: можно так попробовать:  SELECT i.inbox_date AS 'Число', 
       SUM(i.inbox_sum) OVER (PARTITION BY i.inbox_date) AS 'Приход',
       (SELECT o.outbox_sum FROM outbox AS o
          WHERE o.outbox_date = (SELECT inbox_date FROM inbox)) AS 'Расход',
       ((SELECT SUM(p.inbox_sum) OVER (PARTITION BY p.inbox_date) 
          FROM inbox AS p) - 
        (SELECT SUM(r.outbox_sum) OVER (PARTITION BY r.outbox_date) 
          FROM outbox AS r)) AS 'Остаток'
FROM inbox AS i;

Comment: Yaroslav, хотелось бы вытащить всю информацию из БД за один раз а не по числу ...только с группировкой по числам ) А так вывело 23 ошибок

Comment: Mike, немогли бы Вы обьяснить словосочетание "оборачиваете в внешний запрос" ?)

Comment: @Таисия Леркова, дополните вопрос скриптами табличок и тестовых данных!

Comment: @Таисия Леркова, Mike Вам говорит что нужно результат с подзапроса  передать в основной запрос!

Comment: @Yaroslav, имеете виду скрипты как я заполняю таблицу ?

Comment: @Таисия Леркова, ага и самих табличек